# FontFeature (SMCP) not working as expected in Flutter Text

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have the following sample text that I am trying to use small caps on in flutter.

```
Text(
                'This is a Google Font',
                style: GoogleFonts.cardo(
                  textStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontFeatures: [FontFeature.enable('smcp')],
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      letterSpacing: .5),
                  //smcp as in small caps
                ),
              ),
```

The issue is that it shows for a fraction of a second and after I reload is then gone. I tried it in DartPad and it works as expected but on real device and simulator it doesn't.

How can this issue be fixed?